# UNLOAD to a new file when running in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, unload

I am trying to UNLOAD the file to an S3 Bucket. However, I DONT want to overwrite, but create a new file everytime I run the command. How can I achieve this?

```
unload ('select * from table1')
to 's3://bucket/file1/file2/file3/table1.csv' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0934857378:role/RedshiftAccessRole,arn:aws:iam::435874575846546:role/RedshiftAccessRole'
DELIMITER ','
PARALLEL OFF 
HEADER
```

Comment: Could S3 versioning help you with your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the destination path specified in the "TO" section.

If you wish to do this programmatically, you could do it in whatever script/command sends the `UNLOAD` command.

You *might* be able to do it via a Stored Procedure by keeping a table with the last file number and writing code to retrieve and increment it.

Or, you could write an AWS Lambda function that is triggered upon creation of the file. The Lambda function could then copy the object to a different path/filename and delete the original object.